# Android - save value of member field in Fragment class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, android-lifecycle

I'm trying to do something using a `boolean` in a `Fragment` class each time the `Fragment` is displayed.

### Example

My app launches, opens the `FirstFragment` and the `boolean` for the first time is always `true`, then I have an `if` clause that checks its value:

```
if (FirstTime) {
    FirstTime = false;
} else {
    // Other stuff here, cause it's not true.
}
```

Then, on the first time, when `FirstTime` is `true`, I do stuff like go to another `Fragment`. and when I return to `Fragment1` and on my `onCreate()`, I do the same. It's always `true`, seems that it's refreshing or something.

Then I thought that could be a problem with `Fragment`, and every time I press on `Fragment1`, it restarts or something. Then, I've added a getter and setter in my `MainActivity`:

```
public Boolean getFirstTime() {
    return FirstTime;
}

public void setFirstTime(Boolean FirstTime) {
    this.FirstTime = FirstTime;
}
```

where since the start, it's true and then, I changed my code from `Fragment1` for:

```
if (((MainActivity) getActivity()).getFirstTime())
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setFirstTime(false);
} else {
    // Other stuff here, cause it's not true,
}
```

However, it's still saying that's true.

***What I'm doing wrong or what I misunderstood about Fragments?

Is there any way to do it?***

Comment: do you have an application class? if so save it there

Comment: @Elltz what do you mean?

Comment: what i mean is you are having boolean problems? then an easy approach is to create a singleton class that hangs along as long as both your fragments and activities are alive, and create the variable in that class, an example is a class that extends Application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have made an assumption that the `Fragment` instance remains in existence as long as the app is alive. It is a reasonable assumption, and your approach would work fine if that assumption were true.

Unfortunately, a `Fragment` is destroyed when it recedes into the background, and created anew when it returns to the foreground. This is why it appears to "refresh". The same is not true of an `Activity`. When an `Activity` recedes into the background, it is not destroyed immediately. Rather, it is maintained on the current task's backstack for some time, and if it returns to the foreground, it is the *same* instance.

To combat this problem, there are four different ways:

- Declare `FirstTime` as `static`. This *should* work. I've used this before. However, this should only be used in extreme cases when there is an absolute necessity to preserve the value of a member field, and only when no other way is available. Making a variable `static` leads to a classic memory leak.
- Save the value of `FirstTime` in your `Fragment` using [`onSaveInstanceState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29):

  ```
  @Override
  public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
      outState.putBoolean("FirstTime", FirstTime);
  }
  ```

  and retrieve the value in `onCreate()`:

  ```
  @Override
  public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate();
      FirstTime = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("FirstTime");
  }
  ```
- Declare `FirstTime` in a global constants class instead of putting it in the `Fragment`:

  ```
  public class GlobalConstants{

      public static boolean FirstTime = true;
      // other global constants ...

  }
  ```

  and access it in your `Fragment` like this:

  ```
  if (GlobalConstants.FirstTime) {
      GlobalConstants.FirstTime = false;
  } else {
      //Other stuff here cause it's not true
  }
  ```
- Save the value of `FirstTime` in a [`SharedPreference`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html):

  ```
  SharedPreferences sp = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
  editor.putBoolean("FirstTime", FirstTime);
  editor.commit();
  ```

  and retrieve its value in this way:

  ```
  SharedPreferences sp = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  FirstTime = sp.getBoolean("FirstTime", true);
  ```

The first three methods will maintain the value of `FirstTime` while the application is alive. The fourth method will preserve the value of `FirstTime` beyond the lifetime of the application, i.e. when the app restarts, `FirstTime` will be `true` or `false` depending on what its value was last set before the app exited.

**References:**

**1.** [**Handling the Fragment Lifecycle**](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle).

**2.** [**Saving Key-Value Sets**](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).

**3.** [**Visibility and Lifetime**](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx4b.html).

**EDIT:**

To understand how to use `onSaveInstanceState()`, see the following links:

**1.** [**Saving (and Retrieving) Android Instance State**](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/saving-and-retrieving-android-instance-state-part-2/).

**2.** [**Once for all, how to correctly save instance state of Fragments**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313598/once-for-all-how-to-correctly-save-instance-state-of-fragments-in-back-stack).

**3.** [**Handling Configuration Changes**](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Configuration-Changes).

It *is* confusing, but it will be useful to you once you understand it.

Comment: I've tried the GlobalConstant method and it still going throught the if, and the onSaveInstance method I don't get how can I do it. Shall I put the FirstTime like Boolean FirstTime = true; and then do the stuff?

Comment: @Skizo: you are always welcome ... we are all here to help each other :) ... I too need some guidance, for example, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29911046/android-zoom-animation-using-animatorset) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276666/send-a-message-to-a-facebook-friend-from-an-android-app) which I have posted, and I have not received a satisfactory answer for either of them, perhaps you or some of your friends can help me, I'd be most grateful :)

Comment: @Skizo: also, see edited answer above, it may be useful for understanding how to save instance state of `Fragment` and `Activity` ... best :)

Comment: That's really very nice of you, thank you so much :) Why didn't I think of that ?

Comment: @Skizo: I did look at it. I have an idea: can you take a log of the URL that you create in your Java code for the delete operation, and compare it with the URL that you use in Postman ? Are they the same ? Let me know ...

Comment: Yes that does look like a good answer, I plan to try it out soon, thanks again for your selflessness ... :)

Comment: As I said, you deserve it and much more :P Have fun, and let me know when you've got a good answer, also if you need a correct answer in your other question I'll put a bounty too ^^

Comment: No don't worry my friend, I'll put a bounty on it, funny why I never thought of that. That other question is not important at the moment ... :)

Comment: Okay then, I hope the best of luck for you ^^

Comment: Can I ask to you something? it's about an error like this (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f090022 (info.androidhive.slidingmenu:id/frame_container)) and I don't know what happens this, I think it's at the time I do the replace...

Comment: `No view found for id` means that when you call `findViewById()`, that particular `View` is not present in your current layout. Without more detail, it is hard to tell what exactly the problem is ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77260/discussion-between-skizo-and-y-s).

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution, set your boolean to a static.

This of course does not comply to the good practices of programming.

To answer you question more directly, I'm assuming that the fragments and activities get destroyed and new instances are created, hence the boolean being set to true again. As such, by making the variable static, it's state will remain across all instances of that class.

Comment: it's not necessary set & get?

Comment: if you make it public then nope.

Comment: Don't make it static. Save the values in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) `

Comment: @JaredRummler How can I do that?

Comment: As I mentioned, if you are restarting your app entirely, this method will not work.

Comment: I am not :S I'm just opening fragments