# Fragment Transaction - No view found for id 0x7f090022

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to replace a `Fragment` when I click on a item List, the thing is that I've got the same code for 5 differents `fragments` and it works on all, only on this `Fragment` says :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f090022 (info.androidhive.slidingmenu:id/frame_container) for fragment DetallProductePerTipus{3899b306 #1 id=0x7f090022}

It says the `frame_container` is not found... This is how I do the replace :

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = new DetallProductePerTipus();
    bundle.putString("titol", item.title);

    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()

            .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

I had problems with transaction with `Fragments v4` and not `v4`, and then I tried also this :

```
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   Fragment fragment = new DetallProductePerTipus();
    bundle.putString("titol", item.title);

    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()

            .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

but it still doesn't work...

What I'm doing wrong?

On the same `Fragment` I've got this code that makes a replace of a `Fragment`, I want the same but adding the `Bundle`.

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, new ListaProductosFragment());
ft.commit();
```

Comment: No view found for id 0x7f090022 (info.androidhive.slidingmenu:id/frame_container) for fragment. TL;DR, frame_container isnt in your fragment view

Comment: Check you parent activity FrameLayout it should contain a id with name frame_container

Comment: Did you try using getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager() in your code, since you are using Fragment from support v4 and the other case is as @rachar_P suggested "parent activity FrameLayout it should contain a id with name frame_container ".

Comment: I need more details ... can you post all the code related to this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved my problem doing this :

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("titol", item.title);
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = new DetallProducteOffer();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
fm.beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: It seems to be the same as the original code. Do you know what was causing the problem ?

Comment: It's not the same, I just added the `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();` and then I put `fm.beginTransaction()`

Comment: Can you describe what you did besides "I did this" ?