# Unable to modify values in ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I'm faced with this problem

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

What I want to do is easy, I'll show you an example.

### MyList

Blue

Red

Green

When I make an `OnItemLongClickListener()` for example on `Green`, my list should looks like :

### MyList

Green

What I've tried is

```
final ArrayAdapter < String > adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FileBackup.getFilesFound());
adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView <? > arg0, View arg1, final int arg2, long arg3) {
        String itemValue = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
        Log.d("Item clicked --> ", lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString());
        FileBackup.setNameFile(itemValue);
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.user_file_choose);
        Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btOk);
        Button button2 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btKo);
        TextView tvBackUpFile = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textViewContentDialog);
        tvBackUpFile.setText("Do you want to backup " + FileBackup.getNameFile() + " ?");
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                //Clear all the ListView
                lv.setAdapter(null);

            }
        });
    }
});
```

It's working fine, if I want to clear the `ListView`, but in my case I DON'T WANT TO, I tried to add item or remove with :

```
adapter.addAll("Something");
```

or

```
lv.removeViewAt(2);
```

And then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` but it gives the same error every time I try to.

What I'm doing wrong?

### EDIT

Now the code looks like :

```
final ArrayAdapter < String > adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (getActivity(), Arrays.asList(FileBackup.getFilesFound()));
adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView <? > arg0, View arg1, final int arg2, long arg3) {
        String itemValue = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
        Log.d("Item clicked --> ", lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString());
        FileBackup.setNameFile(itemValue);
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.user_file_choose);
        Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btOk);
        Button button2 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btKo);
        TextView tvBackUpFile = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textViewContentDialog);
        tvBackUpFile.setText("Do you want to backup " + FileBackup.getNameFile() + " ?");
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                //Clear all the ListView
                lv.setAdapter(null);
                //Trying to add that current item clicked
                adapter.addAll(FileBackup.getNameFile());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
    }
});
```

And this is the LogCat error :

```
06-10 20:14:43.531    8072-8072/info.androidhive.tabsswipe E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: info.androidhive.tabsswipe, PID: 8072
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:404)
        at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:425)
        at java.util.Collections.addAll(Collections.java:2583)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.addAll(ArrayAdapter.java:211)
        at info.androidhive.tabsswipe.BackupWA$1$1.onClick(BackupWA.java:80)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4456)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18462)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Where it's pointing this --> `adapter.addAll(FileBackup.getNameFile());` but it's not null I also tried to `adapter.addAll("RED");`

### EDIT2

I'm trying to keep the name what I've clicked to `FileBackup.getFilesFound()` so I can create my adapter again I'm doing it with :

```
String[] itemvalues = (String[]) lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
FileBackup.setFilesFound(itemvalues);
```

And then I'm doing :

```
 adapter.addAll(Arrays.asList(FileBackup.getFilesFound()));
 //Add the name
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

On my class is declared as `String[]` and the error is :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]

### EDIT3

It's giving the same error every time I want to update the list... @Y.S. said that It's better to post all of my code to see what's going on, because somewhere I'm using `String[]` instead of `ArrayList<String>`

That's my `FileBackup.java`

```
    public class FileBackup {

    private String path;
    private String pathFile;
    private File FileToBackUp;
    private String SDpath;
    private String[] FilesFound;
    private String nameFile;

    public String getPathFile() {
        return pathFile;
    }

    public void setPathFile(String pathFile) {
        this.pathFile = pathFile;
    }
    public String getNameFile() {
        return nameFile;
    }

    public void setNameFile(String nameFile) {
        this.nameFile = nameFile;
    }

    public FileBackup(String path){
        this.path = path;
    }

    public File getFileToBackUp() {
        return FileToBackUp;
    }

    public void setFileToBackUp(File fileToBackUp) {
        FileToBackUp = fileToBackUp;
    }
public String[] getFilesFound() {
       this.FilesFound = FilesFound();

        return FilesFound;
    }
 public String[] FilesFound() {
        File dir = new File(this.path);
        File[] filelist = dir.listFiles();
        String[] theNamesOfFiles = new String[filelist.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < theNamesOfFiles.length; i++) {

            theNamesOfFiles[i] = filelist[i].getName();
        }

        return theNamesOfFiles;
    }
```

And this is how I have the List of the files.

```
final String itemValue = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

 Log.d("Item clicked --> ", lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString());


 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
 dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.user_file_choose);
 Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btOk);
 Button button2 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btKo);
 FileBackup.setNameFile(itemValue);
 TextView tvBackUpFile = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textViewContentDialog);
 tvBackUpFile.setText("Do you want to backup " + FileBackup.getNameFile() + " ?");
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
         //The complete path of the fail
         FileBackup.setPathFile(GlobalConstant.path + "/" + FileBackup.getNameFile());
         //Converting the path of the file to a File and putting it to FileToBackUp
         FileBackup.setFileToBackUp(PathToFile(FileBackup.getPathFile()));

         dialog.dismiss();
         //Clear all the ListView
         lv.setAdapter(null);

         //Add the name
         BackUpFile.setEnabled(true);


     }
 });
```

I tried to do something like :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //The complete path of the fail
        FileBackup.setPathFile(GlobalConstant.path + "/" + FileBackup.getNameFile());
        //Converting the path of the file to a File and putting it to FileToBackUp
        FileBackup.setFileToBackUp(PathToFile(FileBackup.getPathFile()));
        ///// THIS IS NEW ///////////
        String itemvalues = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
        FileBackup.setFilesFound(new String[] {
            itemvalues
        });
        adapter.addAll(FileBackup.getFilesFound());
        //Add the name
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //////////TIL HERE/////////////
        dialog.dismiss();
        //Clear all the ListView


        //Add the name
        BackUpFile.setEnabled(true);


    }
});
```

And this is the LogCat

```
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:404)
        at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:425)
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:76)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.addAll(ArrayAdapter.java:195)
        at info.androidhive.tabsswipe.BackupWA$1$1.onClick(BackupWA.java:88)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4456)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18462)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Where is pointing

```
adapter.addAll(Arrays.asList(FileBackup.getFilesFound()));
```

Also I've tried with

```
adapter.addAll(FileBackup.getFilesFound());
```

But it's giving the same error... Maybe is that I'm doing this on a not correct place...

Comment: possibly thre is no view at position 2

Comment: That was just an example, and yes it is, becase I can see the ListView

Comment: Could you please post the full stack trace of the error along with line numbers for the code snippet?

Comment: @matt5784 Done on my edit

Comment: have you found a solution for this question ?

Comment: Not yet, do you see something wrong on my edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look this answer:
[ArrayAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200551/unable-to-modify-arrayadapter-in-listview-unsupportedoperationexception)

So basically as in this answer said: *"The ArrayAdapter, on being initialized by an array, converts the array into a AbstractList (List) which cannot be modified."*

So it easy, create your own ArrayList, in your case of type String, and then assign this to CustomAdapter, then you can just remove items from your ArrayList and notifyDataSetChanged() should works.

Regards