# Switch on AppCompatActivity not showing

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a `Switch` widget on my `ActionBar` but when I try to implement it it doesn't show or if it does, my `ActionBart` title dissapears.
What I've done is :

I've created a `Layout` for this `Switch`

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/switchAB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And then on my `menu_main.xml` I've added this :

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/switchId"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/swipe_wifi"
    />
```

I've changed `android` to `app` because on help says so

[image]

Then on my ActivityMain `onCreateOptionsMenu()` if added this to make a fast test

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    switchAB = (Switch)menu.findItem(R.id.switchId)
            .getActionView().findViewById(R.id.switchAB);

    switchAB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                     boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

But it's giving to me a `NPE` on this lane

```
 switchAB = (Switch)menu.findItem(R.id.switchId)
        //NPE-->    .getActionView().findViewById(R.id.switchAB);
```

Shall I change something on my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `app:actionLayout` too:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/switchId"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/swipe_wifi"
    />
```

It should be noted also that you are casting the view to `android.widget.Switch`, while in your layout you have a `android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat` (and that is a good choice, since `Switch` was added in API14).

Comment: No luck... it still giving me a NPE but not on the same place I think is on the `setOnCheckedChangeListener()`

Comment: Please post your updated code and highlight the line which is throwing the error. Did you change your cast to SwitchCompat as said?

Comment: Shall I remove the `Compat`?

Comment: Oh Sh*t.... that was the error... I changed to `android.widget.Switch` and it works! Thank you :)