# EditText decimal value

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm implementing `EditText`'s and I'm facing with one issue... I've put that the `inputType` is `numberDecimal` but at the time I type on the `EditText` I'd like to put the "." or "," autommatically... 
I can put for example `100.00` or `90.00` it depends of the user... Can it be possible?

I tried to create a `TextWatcher` and do some things on `onTextChanged` like see if the `charSequence-lenght()==2` add a "." or "," but doesn't work...

Can I detect when to put the comma or dot even if I have a decimal format like `##.##` or `###.##` ? As I said it can be `100.00` or `80.00`.

### Edit

```
 @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        //et1 and et2 are not empty
        if(et1.getText().toString().length() == 5 && et2.getText().toString().length() == 5){
            double pe1 , pe2;
            pe1 = Double.parseDouble(et1.getText().toString());
            pe2 = Double.parseDouble(et2.getText().toString());
            double res = (pe1+pe2)/2;
            String formattedString = String.format("%,.2f", res);
            tvPr.setText(formattedString);

        }
```

The problem is on the textInput not on `afterTextChanged` I guess... because I have to put the "." manually and I want to avoid this.

### EDIT2

Also a friend of mine suggested to me that I could ignore the . and , and since the marks are always 100, 80, 32, etc... on the editText just type those numbers but then tract those as a double and I'd like to put a ,00 when the user finish the editting of editText is that possible?

Are the comparation `if(et1.getText().toString().length() == 5 && et2.getText().toString().length() == 5){` good at the time to check wheter is an edittext not empty? I have to update a TextView once both edittext are not empty and do some operations so, I tried this way, is there another one better? (I put lenght()==5 because on EditText I put maxlenght() = 5;

Comment: Don't get you what do you mean?

Comment: The thing is that I don't know when the user will put 100.00 or 80.00

Comment: Decimal formats can be set to only care about what comes after the decimal, not so much before it. "#.00" means that you want to round any double to exactly 2 decimal places.

Comment: but I need to know how to add the "." when typing and I'd like to know if it's a good approach look for if the first is an 1 and then a 0 and then 0 put "."

Comment: You take the editable, convert it to a string, format it using decimal format, and apply the formatted string to the edit text. You don't have to manually insert the decimal anywhere, the formatter does it for you.

Comment: The thing is that I have a textWatcher to check if the 2 edittext are not empty to update a TextView, so shall I put your code that you are saying to me before the if condition?

Comment: Nope, put it after. Just try it out, play with it some, you aren't going to blow your phone up or anything :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112812/discussion-between-stuart2041-and-zgc7009).

Comment: You are making this way too complicated. All you have to do is check if the editable has any length and if so convert it to a double.

Comment: @zgc7009 could you post a sample or something to guide me?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is something like this

```
final DecialFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String value = s.toString();
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(value)){
            // do what you want if it is empty
            return;
        }

        try {
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
            String testFormat = df.format(Double.parseDouble(s.toString()));

            // Manage the cursor position
            int newPos;
            try {
                int pos = et.getSelectionStart();
                int sizeDiff = testFormat.length() - s.length();
                newPos = pos + sizeDiff;
            }catch(Exception e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();
                newPos = testFormat.length();
            }

            // Modify the edit text to hold the double value
            et.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            et.setText(testFormat);
            et.setSelection(newPos);
            et.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            et.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            et.setText("");
            et.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Modify the above code to do what you need, but this is the basic idea behind making sure the value is of decimal form. It is worth mentioning that when you modify text like this the cursor position is always a "fun" thing to try to get how you want it. What happens if you have "100.00" and someone puts the cursor in a place like "100.0|0" and presses 5. Should the result be "100.0|5" or "100.05|" and if it is the latter how do you handle them putting in the next value, do you use it to round the previous value? It is an interesting situation, but this will get you started.

Comment: This is not adding the "." and this is making the edittext focus always the first letter I mean the line cursor is always on the left side and writing like 54321 if you want to type 12345

Comment: Look at the modifications, if you are not getting the decimal appropriately you are doing something wrong elsewhere in your code @Stuart2041

Comment: nice answer, I followed up with another one, but it'd work I guess :), one doubt... Could I add an event to change a TextView? I mean if I have 2 TextViews that the value changes dynammically how could I change the thirth one if those are moddifieds?

Comment: @Stuart2041 check out observables

Comment: But I can make my TextView be observable?

Comment: Was looking for observable and I don't find the way to make only 1 TextView observable and changing the value only when other 2 TextView changes the value....