# Get value from CheckBox in custom ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox

Well I have implemendes a HashMap where the key is a String and the value is a Integer the thing is that I'd like to know how could I get the value of the radio button clicked, to get the value, and then if I could do some operations with them, for example:

Cb1 2 Checked

Cb2 9 Checked

Cb3 19 UnChecked

> The output should be 11 (2+9)

So I'd like to make a sum of checked ones and update a TextView with that value.

From now I have this :

This is the HashMap

```
HashMap<String, Integer> hmAs = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
```

And this is how I create the Dialog

```
Dialog mDialog;
mDialog=new Dialog(this);
mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_as);
ListView lv = (ListView) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.listView);
Button bt = (Button) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.btAcceptAs);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mDialog.dismiss();
                       //Here I need the sum of all of the values
        }
    });
ArrayAdapter adapter = new HashMapArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, new ArrayList(hmAs.entrySet()));
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
mDialog.show();
```

And this is the Adapter

```
class HashMapArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

Context mContext;

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tV1;
    CheckBox cb;
}

public HashMapArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_item_dialog, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tV1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDataAs);
        viewHolder.cb = (Checkbox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = (Map.Entry<String, Integer>) this.getItem(position);

    viewHolder.tV1.setText(entry.getKey());
    viewHolder.rb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, String.valueOf(entry.getValue()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
}
```

With this `Toast` I get the exact value of the `map` but the problem is how from the dialog, that I have the `Button` when I press "Accept" I can get the sum of all of the `CheckBox` of the `ListView`

### EDIT

Well I ended up doing something like this :

I created a class that is called `Sessio` which contains an `int` (value of the sessio) and a `boolean` to check if the checkbox is checked or not. well I have to save the checkeds on `SharedPreferences` and I've been reading here on SO and you'll recomend that don't save a `HashMap` on `SharedPreferences` since it requieres lot of memory, well.. so the idea is the same, I have to save all of the hashmap and which one is clicked or not, I think the stuff to count the `CheckBox` ...

Answer (score 0):

> Press "Accept" I can get the sum of all of the CheckBox of the
>   ListView

Create a method inside `HashMapArrayAdapter` which return checked entry value and call it on `Accept` Button click:

**1.** Declare a HashMap with position as key and `entry.getValue()` as key for storing checked CheckBox values:

```
Map<Integer, String> checkedCheckBoxValues = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

**2.** Now create a method which return `HashMap<Integer, String>` in `HashMapArrayAdapter` class :

```
public HashMap<Integer, String> getCheckedCheckBoxs(){
  return checkedCheckBoxValues;
}
```

**3.** Add key and value inside  `onCheckedChanged` to `checkedCheckBoxValues` :

```
checkedCheckBoxValues.put(position,String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
```

**4.** Call `getCheckedCheckBoxs` method on `Accept` Button click using `adapter`:

```
  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       mDialog.dismiss();
       HashMap<Integer, String> checkedValues=adapter.getCheckedCheckBoxs();
    }
```

Comment: I was trying to do the same hahaha I just overrided the `getCount()` and by parameter I pass the total of the sum of the values (all of the checkbox are checkeds) and then on the onCheckedChanged I put if(checked) sum = sum + entry.value() else sum = sum - entry.value() but I'll try your question... I'll let you know how's going

Comment: @Stuart2041: ok try it

Comment: from start I tried to do it without overriding but I did it because when I created a method inside of the adapter it didn't let me call it from Activity it says cannot resolve method

Comment: I'd like to save the hash map to Shared prefernces because when I press again on button if I changed the state of the checkbox it doesn't update, so it's a good approach to create a getter that returns the same HashMap?